# C++ overloading operator with multiple inheritance from templates

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, operator-overloading

I have an hierarchy that represents some part of an HTTP client and looks like this:

```
typedef list<pair<string, string> > KeyVal;
struct Header { string name; string value; ...};
struct Param { string name; string value; ...};

/* Something that contains headers */
template<typename T> class WithHeaders {
  KeyVal headers;
public:
  virtual T &operator <<(const Header &h) {
    headers.push_back(pair<string, string>(h.name, h.value));
    return static_cast<T&> (*this);
  }
};

/* Something that contains query params */
template<class T> class WithQuery {
    KeyVal query_params;

public:
    virtual T &operator <<(const Param &q) {
      query_params.push_back(pair<string, string>(q.name, q.value));
      return static_cast<T&> (*this);
    }

    const KeyVal &get_query() const {return query_params;}
};

/* Http Request has both headers and query parameters */
class Request: public WithQuery<Request>, public WithHeaders<Request> {...};
```

So that I expected to be able to do things like `request << Header(name, value) << Param("page", "1")` (and later will reuse `WithHeaders` in the corresponding `Response` class).

The code that I'm trying to compile is:

```
Request rq = Request("unused", "unused", "unused");
rq << Header("name", "value");
```

However, I get:

```
test/test_client.cpp:15:30: error: request for member ‘operator<<’ is ambiguous
In file included from test/test_client.cpp:1:0:
test/../client.h:45:16: error: candidates are: 
    T& WithQuery<T>::operator<<(const Param&) [with T = Request]         
    T& WithHeaders<T>::operator<<(const Header&) [with T = Request]
```

I must be missing something, but it seems quite easy to distinguish `Param` from `Header` during the compilation time. So, the questions are:

- why does it fail and how to fix it?
- is that a reasonable thing to do at all or there's a simpler design?

Comment: Please show the exact code which is giving you the error. Also, your `q` parameter should probably be taken by `const&`. And are there any converting ctors or operators in `Header` or `Param`?

Comment: @Angew added the code. `const` was missing, indeed. There are no converting ctors (tried to do `Header h = Param("a", "b")`, that failed).

Comment: What is the relation between `HttpRequest` and `Request`? from the code it seems that the operator<< will return a reference to an object of type Request, while it seems your object is of type HttpRequest.

Comment: My bad, that's mistake during the code copying (see the comment to @Joachim's answer). Fixed.

Comment: what compiler are you using? to me this seems like some sort of compiler bug, a slightly modified example [compiles under `clang++`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0749bab057ef385d) but [fails with `g++`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f8e26c15c188dcf).

Comment: @refp using g++, so that must be some compiler bug indeed =(

Comment: I'll dig deeper into the standard and will try to come up with a definite answer to see which one of the two compilers is doing the correct thing. The error message from `g++` sure is confusing, but maybe name-hiding makes the code illegal (and therefore it shouldn't compile).

Comment: `g++` is doing the correct thing by rejecting the code (even though the error message is misleading). If a *name* isn't present in the derived class but present in more than one base class neither should be considered when doing the look-up. The exact rules in standardees can be read at `10.2/6-7` in the standard.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<s>I believe it should work, so it's most likely a GCC bug.</s> *As pointed out by @refp in the comments, the lookup is actually ambiguous and GCC is correct in rejecting it.*

This is how you make it work:

```
class Request: public WithQuery<Request>, public WithHeaders<Request> {
public:
    using WithHeaders<Request>::operator<<;
    using WithQuery<Request>::operator<<;
};
```

[**Live example**](http://ideone.com/N53E0S)

Comment: Not sure if it's a GCC bug, *inheritance* + *name-resolution* in the standard might say that the code is illegal (your fix sure fixes that though).

Comment: That's amasing, thanks! But what exactly does that mean and why does that make difference?

Comment: @bereal A declaration `using X` brings the name `X` into the scope where the declaration appears. In other words, here you explicitly signal that `Request` has member functions `WithHeaders<Request>::operator<<` and `WithQuery<Request>::operator<<`. This simplifies name lookup.

Comment: @refp Could be. I don't have the time to look up the name lookup rules now [ ;-) ], but my gut feeling is it should find both and overload resolution should pick the correct one.

Comment: @Angew I'm reading the standard and this doesn't seem to be the case, the original code is ill-formed if I interpret `10.2/6` correctly. I will read it more carefully and see if I find a definite answer.

Comment: @Angew see `10.2/6-7`, the program is informed and `gcc` is doing the right thing to reject it, even though (as usual) the error message isn't of much help.