# Who is wrong gcc or clang and why?

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc

gcc fails to compile this code, but clang compiles it well.

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5368862/why-do-multiple-inherited-functions-with-same-name-but-different-signatures-not) gcc is right. Because there is several base classes with the same function name - `operator()`, which is an ambiguity

Is it really clang bug? Or may be there is special lookup rules for `operator()` in standard or something else not so obvious?

```
#include <utility>

template <class... Ts>
class TMultiLambda: public Ts... {
public:
    template <class... Fs>
    TMultiLambda(Fs&&... Vs) noexcept: Ts(std::forward<Fs>(Vs))... {
    }
};
template <class... Ts>
auto MakeMultiLambda(Ts&&... Vs) noexcept -> TMultiLambda<std::remove_reference_t<Ts>...> {
    return { std::forward<Ts>(Vs)... };
}

int main() {
    int x;
    auto a = [x](int, int) { };
    auto b = [x] (char) { };
    auto c = MakeMultiLambda(a, b);
    c(2, 2);
    c('q');
    return 0;
}
```

P.S.
You can compile code online [here](http://gcc.godbolt.org/), do not forget to append `-std=c++1y` to compiler options

Comment: What about the question you linked didn't answer your question?

Comment: @Barry Operator lookup might make a difference. (But it doesn't.)

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/19159784/

Comment: @Barry Ah, that's the one I've been looking for :)

Comment: @Barry in this case I use lambdas, and they could be handled/treated in some special way. For example they can at some conditions define implicit conversion operator (see ClosureType::operator ret(*)(params)() at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda), which in its turn can somehow affect lookup rules.